# Flutter dynamic tabbar rendering (async)

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dynamic, tabbar

I would like to render a tab bar dynamically from SQLite. with:

In

```
void initState() {
```

I retrieve the necessary

```
Future<List<MyClass>> list
```

with

```
 getAllMyClasses().then((onValue) {
       list=value;
     });
```

but this (the above code) returns later than the

```
 @override   
 Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
     return new DefaultTabController(
```

code runs, so the tab controller does not know the number of tabs (length), the tabs of the TabBar and the widgets of the TabBarView.

How to resolve this? How could I ensure the building rendering to wait for initstate (including the async `getAllMyClasses()`) function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can show a `CircularProgressIndicator` till your list is null and show `TabBar` when have data.

```
@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return list==null ? CircularProgressIndicator() : DefaultTabController(...);
}
```

Also, use `setState` to rebuild the widgets again.

```
 getAllMyClasses().then((onValue) {
       //this will notify that internal state has changed and widgets will be rebuild
       setState((){
          list=value;
       });
     });
```